# iPhone - Core Date Model Versioning - versioning after the fact? Issues with project.pbxproj?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I have an app that I have been working on and I did a bunch of changes and then realized later I should have been adding versioning to the Core Data model. So I'm trying to go back and do that now.

Basic information:

- I think everything I've done would fall under the lightweight migration feature.
- I'm using git
- I already have the app in user's hands

My question is: what is the easiest way to do this?

Since I'm using git, could I simply checkout the data model from when I submitted it to apple, create a new version for it, and add my changes? My main fear with this idea is that my project.pbxproj file would be incorrect. Would this an issue? Is there a way to get around this?

IF I could do this, would I need to recreate my class files or would that be ok (assuming I get it back to being identical to what I currently have).

IF I CAN'T do this, then what can I do? If its a matter of starting from the last version I pushed to Apple and applying changes I guess I should look into doing it with git rebase, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with git.

You need to create a new version of your app, provide the new data model, set it for lightweight migration and then release it as an update. Core Data will basically assume that any model without version info is version zero and attempt a migration to the new version.

When the user downloads the update, the automatic migration will trigger the first time the app runs.

Creating a new version means nothing more than changing the version number in the project info. When submitted, that will trigger the upgrade and the migration.